# Arduino strange behaviour dtostrf

Tags: arduino

I do not know what's wrong with this code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char dataH[5];
  char dataC[5];
  char dataF[5];

  float h = 56.00;
  float c = 31.50;
  float f = 88.70;

  dtostrf(h,5,2,dataH);
  dtostrf(c,5,2,dataC);
  dtostrf(f,5,2,dataF);

  Serial.println(dataH);
  Serial.println(dataC);
  Serial.println(dataF);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I am expecting these as the result:

```
56.00
31.50
88.70
```

Instead, this is what I got:

```
blank  
blank  
88.70
```

The first 2 lines were blank (i wrote with text blank otherwise it will skipped by stackoverflow. :(

Comment: This is not C ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare your character arrays as

```
  char dataH[6];
  char dataC[6];
  char dataF[6];
```

so that they have space to store `'\0'` at the end

Comment: Thanks Pras. This should be the correct answer. I just need to store 1 more space.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this my fault. After looking to its [doc](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html), I need to create buffer.

```
char buff[5];
dataH = dtostrf(h,5,2,buff);
```

I think the buff will immediately garbage collected and will be gone if not consume in next statement.

Comment: Nonsense, there is no garbage collection at all. However in the same doc is mentioned "Caller is responsible for providing sufficient space", and you have failed to do that (as mentioned in @Pras answer). This is called a buffer overflow.